# Overriding error messages for all validation attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, system.componentmodel

I'm using`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` attributes for validation but want to get error messages not from hard-coded strings or resources but from external service. The solution I've found so far requires too much code - create adapter factories for *each* of the attributes, create a validator provider and replace `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider` in `ModelValidatorProviders.Providers` with my own. Is there a better way, some kind of extension point where code could "wrap" all the calls to validation and still has access to attribute itself because I use `ErrorMessageResourceType` and `ErrorMessageResourceName` as key to locate proper strings in external service.

(I'm using MVC 5, not ASP.NET Core where this problem looks to be solved)